# SQL Server prevent SA from setting encryption off

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Is there a way to prevent any user (including SA) from setting database encryption off (unless password or physical file - cert is provided)?

That is: not just some column or specific data - but securing the whole database from being detached and used on another server.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to prevent any user (including SA) from setting database encryption off …?

No.  If the database is ONLINE then a sysadmin (including SA) can remove TDE.  Sysadmins are the owners of the SQL Instance, and all the databases.

Comment: +1. In addition you can change **SA** name to something less obvious